# Unexplained connections from one SQL server to another

Tags: sql-server-2016, high-availability, connections

I just installed 2 SQL Server 2016 Enterprise and configured a High Availabilty Group. As a test object for the HA-Group I used a database I restored from another server. It's a database called "dbtools" which only contains objects related to Ola Hallengren's Maintenance Solution, i.e. four StoredProcedures and a Log Table. And Oh - it also contains 2 SP's from BrentOzar (BlitzIndex) and one sp named sp_WhoIsActive which I found somewhere not so long ago.
I have looked at these sp's and found no reference to any server.

Can anyone give me any ideas how to start looking for the reason for these Connections?

- oh, I just realized: The Cluster witness is a shared folder on this other server - but I can't see why master and msdb databases should be queried?

sp_Who2 gives these lines:
[image: Why would the new cluster connect to master and msdb databases on this server]

edit: explanation for the image: the results from sp_who2 is from "serverA", a standalone SQL2016 - "clusternode" is Another server, namely the one holding the HA Group in my Always On cluster. I don't understand why one part of a two-node cluster would take such interest in a server outside the cluster?

Comment: Looks like normal SQL Agent activity to me.

Comment: I would suggest looking up AG healthchecks which will provide more information around the kinds of things that you might see, as well as SQL Agent tasks, and endpoint connections for the AG. And CEIP is the telemetry stuff in 2016.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, sp_BlitzErikand Nic. I also Think it looks like normal SQL Agent activity - except that it's from a server in a 2-node cluster to a server outside that cluster.
My fear is that I will get system failures due to the agent on the cluster node trying to perform activities on the other server

Comment: What do you mean outside that cluster? The Hostname is ClusterNode1 - is clusternode1 not part of the cluster?

Comment: The image shows results from sp_who2 on the standalone server that is not in the cluster. For some reason the active clusternode has connections to this server. I can't see a reason for this.